# How to get TODAY dynamically in orgmode spreadsheet?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How to get the current day dynamically in orgmode spreadsheet? Is there any function?

Comment: you can define the function for TODAY and then use that to insert it. =(function arguments)

Comment: For org-capture there is %t and %T. See more at: http://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html#Template-expansion

Comment: @PuercoPop: but I want it in table :)

Comment: @TruongHa Sourcediving a little I found there is org-current-time, current-time (the opoch) and current-time-string (pretty printed). There is also more time-related functions inside time-date.el